# ReactiveUI + WPF: ListBox items are displayed with correct view except when inside a custom UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I have some view

```
public class MyItem : ReactiveUserControl<MyItemViewModel> {...
```

with some corresponding xaml and the below call sets up the viewmodel to view registration for me

```
Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterViewsForViewModels(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
```

When I bind the ItemsSource property of a ListBox, the items are displayed with the registered view.  However, when I define a UserControl that includes a ListBox

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Views.NavItem"
...
    <StackPanel>
...
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsSource}">
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

and bind to its ItemsSource, the items are displayed with .ToString().

**How can I get my custom UserControl's ListBox items to display using the registered view?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ReactiveUI binding to get automatic view resolution not Xaml binding.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  To clarify, I am using a ReactiveUI binding from pure wpf+xaml custom UserControl to a ReactiveObject viewmodel.  However, there is a xaml binding from the custom UserControl to its own ListBox.  Are you saying that this binding need to be a ReactiveUI created binding?  Also, you said 'to get automatic view resolution': Is there a way to set this up manually?  For example, implementing IViewFor somewhere?

Comment: You can use a ViewModelViewHost and pass the ViewModel to do automatic resolution when using Xaml based bindings https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/86283536c38a84e2f5a4b92e69076903c25b551a/src/ReactiveUI.Uwp/Common/ViewModelViewHost.cs#L48